# store procedures in parameter php error

Tags: php, stored-procedures, mysqli

I have two store procedures, nearly identical, the only difference being that the second one has a in param.

The sp without the param works fine generates a empty table. I have tested the store procedure on my localhost server, so there is nothing wrong with store procedure as such.

I have also corrected some code where I was mixing procedural and oop coding in mysqli. Thanks to "gmc" I rectified that.
This is my code:

```
    //sp

//This store proc without in params is working
echo "<h4>Författartabellen hämtad från databasen med en store procedure</h4>";
  $result_sp = mysqli_query($conn, "CALL jokes");

  //loop the result set
 echo "<table><tr><th>Joke</th><th>AuthorName</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_sp)) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["joketext"]."</td><td>".$row["name"]."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

// This store proc with in param is not working, returns a empty table
//run the store proc
echo "<h4>Författartabellen hämtad från databasen med en store procedure</h4>";
  $result_sp_in = mysqli_query($conn, 'CALL jokes_author("Joan Smith")');

  //loop the result set
 echo "<table><tr><th>Joke</th><th>AuthorName</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_sp_in)) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["joketext"]."</td><td>".$row["name"]."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

Thanks

Comment: You are using the procedural style of `mysqli`, therefore you cannot use its result as an object

Comment: so the procedural style of mysqli can never be used with stored procedures with parameters, only with stored procedures without parameters then?
So the OOP style of mysqli will work with this?

Comment: You can, but then you must fecth assoc also usign the prodcedural style: `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_sp_in)`

Comment: Thanks, now I am not getting any error but a empty table. I have checked that my in param has the correct string in the table

Comment: Could you please show how that code would look like using Procedural style?

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: try this:

```
$result_sp_in = mysqli_query($mysqli, 'CALL jokes_author("Joan Smith", @joketext, @name)');
$select = mysqli_query($mysqli, 'SELECT @joketext, @name');
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select)) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$row["joketext"]."</td><td>".$row["name"]."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: I have previously already corrected my code for that, this is the sp with no param.
Its the sp with the param that is showing a empty table which is using $result_sp_in

Comment: So instead of mysqli_fetch_assoc, I should try with mysqli_fetch_array?

Should it not be $result_sp_in in the mysqli_fetch_array argument, I tried that out also, its still showing me a empty table

Comment: Are you sure that your MySQL procedure works properly?

Comment: Yeah, I tested the same proc on my mysql localhost also with same in param and it works when calling the sp within the database itself. 
But should the in param: 
'CALL jokes_author("John Smith")' 
be with single or double or no quotations marks at all?

Comment: With the quotes i wrote should work. Try: `$result_sp_in = mysqli_query($conn, 'CALL jokes_author("%John%")');`

Comment: I tried that out also with same empty table reply :( I will edit the code I tried for this and upload it soon

Comment: Strangely I was able to solve it when I used the mysqli oop syntax, there the sp with param loaded the results in the table.